# Logged In Using PHP auth or session after activation

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, is there any way to direct logged the user in after the activation was success using PHP authentication (auth) or session?

Here is my activation script:

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "your_private_key";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
// What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
"(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
} else {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$activation_code = $_POST['activation_code'];
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "databasename";
$db_use = "root";
$db_pass = "password";
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_use, $db_pass);
mysqli_select_db($db_name, $link);
$command = "UPDATE email_activation SET check_activation='$activation_code' WHERE username='$username' and activation='$activation_code'";
$result = mysqli_query($command);
if ($result) {
echo "Congratulations. Your membership has been activated …";
}else{
echo ("You've entered an invalid username / activation code – please retry");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you calling `session_start`?

Comment: How to use session start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can.. just put this code after this

```
if ($result) {
echo "Congratulations. Your membership has been activated …";
$_SESSION['user_logged'] = '1';
header("location:afterloginpage.php");
}else{
echo ("You've entered an invalid username / activation code – please retry");
}
}
```

or if you want to save session, you can always check if session is set or not

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user_logged'])) {
  //User directly logged in
}else {
  //Navigate user to login page
  header("location:loginpage.php");
}
```

also dont forget to initialize session_start(); at the top of the php file

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
if ($result) {
    header("Refresh: 5; url=next_file.php");
    echo "Congratulations. Your membership has been activated … If your not redirected in 5 seconds, please click <a href='next_file.php'>here</a>";
}
```